# Bug with RegExp

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I a m working on multiple choice.Here is my code:

```js
$(function() {
  var q;
  var r;
  $("body").on("click", "a[id*='addQues']", function() {

    var identity = $(this).attr('id');
    /\[([0-9]+)\]$/.exec(identity);
    var qbis = parseInt(RegExp.$1);
    q = (qbis + 1);

    $('<label for="nomQues[' + q + ']">Question ' + q + ': </label><input type="text" name="nomQues[' + q + ']" id="nomQues[' + q + ']"/><br/><input type="radio" name="quesType[' + q + ']" value="VF[' + q + ']" id="VF[' + q + ']"/><label for="VF[' + q + ']">Vrai/Faux</label><input type="radio" name="quesType[' + q + ']" value="QCM[' + q + ']" id="QCM[' + q + ']"/><label for="QCM[' + q + ']">QCM</label><input type="radio" name="quesType[' + q + ']" value="QCU[' + q + ']" id="QCU[' + q + ']"/><label for="QCU[' + q + ']">QCU</label><br/><hr id="bar[' + q + ']"/>').insertAfter($(this));
    $('a[id="addQues[' + qbis + ']"]').remove();
    $('<a id="addQues[' + q + ']">Ajouter une question</a>').insertAfter($("#bar\\[" + q + "\\]"));

  });

  $("body").on('change', 'input[name*="quesType"]', function() {

    var identity1 = $(this).attr('name');
    var regex1 = new RegExp("\\[([0-9]+)\\]$");
    var result1 = regex1.exec(identity1);
    q = parseInt(result1[0]);

    var identity2 = $("input[name*='[" + q + "][" + r + "]']").attr('name');
    var regex2 = new RegExp("\\[([0-9]+)\\]$");
    var result2 = regex2.exec(identity2);
    r = parseInt(result2[0]);
    alert("One");

    if (isNaN(r)) {
      r = 1;
      alert("Two");

    } else {
      alert("Three");

    }

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <title>QCM</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
  <section>

    <label for="nameQuizz">Question:</label>
    <input type="text" name="nameQuizz" id="nameQuizz" />
    <br/>
    <hr/>
    <a href=# id="addQues[0]">Add a question</a>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Why alert("One") does not appear? Do you have an explanation? I suppose the problem is due to the creation of the RegExp variables but I am not sure because it seems a good method to use RegExp (according to the MDN).
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Don't just fill in your question with garbage. That message is there for a reason. Explain what you've done to try and find the problem yourself. Don't expect someone to just hand you the solution.

Comment: You can simplify your problem by using `data-*` prefixed custom attribute which can be easily retrieved using `Element.dataset` property. You can use it like `<a href=# class="addQues" data-id="0">Add a question</a>` _It will save you from the regex web_

Comment: SO does not allow alert. Change to console.log. Also console says: `r = parseInt(result2[0])- js:59 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null` so result2 does not exist

Comment: Why not just `q = parseInt(this.id.replace(/[^0-9]/g,""),10) + 1;`

Comment: @Satpal Thank you. I will see in details how it works.

Comment: @mplungjan Thank you, you was right. My problem comes from result2. Why do you propose to use replace()? I do not need to replace number inside id by "". I just want to know the value of the variable q.

Comment: My code gives you q by removing all non numbers. Much simpler than your regex

Comment: @mplungjan Ok, I just understood how your code works. Thank you because it is very efficient.